# Windows Impersonation Java from *nix

Tags: java, unix, winapi, impersonation

I want to replace a legacy application running on Windows server by rewriting it in Java. This application is now connecting to a bunch of Windows servers (which are unavailable for installing another services and it is impossible to change them) via Windows Impersonation API.

I have come up with two libraries [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) and [Waffle](http://dblock.github.io/waffle/README.html). To my understanding, Waffle uses JNA, and JNA provides calls to Windows API from java code.

The thing is, I will have my java application running on a redhat server which obviously does not have win32 api. Is there a *nix binding for [Impersonation API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246062.aspx)? At least I may consider writing JNI over that binding.

I think there should be a way, because Mono and Wine provide similar abstractions on different platforms.

Comment: *"I want to replace a legacy application running on Windows server by rewriting it"* - [Things You Should Never Do, Part I](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/).

Comment: I believe the UNIX equivalent of impersonation is the seteuid function.  Whether you can invoke this from Java I have no idea.  But it actually sounds as if you're wanting to open a named pipe to a Windows server, or perhaps RPC or Schannel?  These aren't all part of some "impersonation API", they are various different communication technologies that all happen to support impersonation.  Please clarify which specific technology you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checking on Mono or Wine to see it is supports impersonation? I don't believe it supports.

I think remote impersonation is encapsulated a lot of technologies, and some of it maybe undocumented. It might be very hard task to writing the client application to support server impersonation without using Windows API. The best way should be continue running on Windows. But if you really want to move the system to run on *nix, the best way should be create a proxy between *nix and Windows. Then later you can completely running on *nix when you don't need the services that running on Windows.